# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space:Trying to use jasper exportreport method

Tags: java, performance, jasper-reports

Getting memory out of error while using jaspers exportreport method. The stack trace is given below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator.readFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator.readTables(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.BreakIterator.createBreakInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.BreakIterator.getBreakInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.BreakIterator.getLineInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:655)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:367)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:511)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.prepare(JRFillTextField.java:607)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:393)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:352)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2023)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:755)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:285)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:132)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:540)
    at com.aricent.aircell.logpatternanalyzer.report.JasperReportUtils.exportReport(JasperReportUtils.java:86)
```

Also I have tried memory leak analyser and as well as jvisualvm to find out the root cause, but it shows `char[]` occupying more than 90%. how to find out the exact root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the Xmx settings is the problem. You should make sure that it's set high enough. If you suspect that anything else might be the problem you can always create a heapdump when you run oom and check that there is no leaking objects. This can be done by adding two parameters.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/heapdump
```

You can then analyze it with jvisualvm or Eclipse MAT (Memory Analyzer Tool)

Comment: i have tried both... it showing that char[] occupying more memory. but  dono how to find out the exact root cause of this problem.

Comment: What is your current xmx and xms settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the heap size (Xmx)? It could happen that the report export simply need more memory. Is it working for smaller reports?

Comment: For smaller reports, its working fine. i have tried the Xmx option with 1024. Even though i am getting the exception.

Comment: I would suggest to increase heap further -if it is possible. And give it another try.

Comment: Is it really necessary to create that huge report? Can you think about something to limit the size?

Answer (score 0):

Are you try to use Virtualizer for fillReport?

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/520261/large-report-virtualizer-solution